# EF Check a Lazy Property without load it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I have an instance of class loaded by db.MyclassSet.AsNoTracking(). So the entity is not tracked on the context. I need to know if the OneToMany property of MyClass is loaded.

If I try to access by reflections I get an exception:

> When an object is returned with a NoTracking merge option, Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469699/how-to-determine-if-navigation-property-in-the-entity-framework-is-set-without-l

Comment: unfortunately no, my datas was loaded with AsNoTracking, so I could not use context.