# Correct way to check if greedily-loaded Entity was loaded after context disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Probably not pertinent, but I'm using:

> .NET MVC 5.2.3 w/ Razor 3.2.3, Entity Framework 6.1.3 `Code First`, Visual Studio 2015.

Okay, in my controller method, I have--in essence, but dumbed down for conciseness:

```
using( var context = new MyContext() ) {
    var person = context.Persons.Include( x => x.PostalCode ).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(person);
}
```

Now, originally the Zip data entry property was not a foreign key...just whatever 5-digit string the user entered.  Now, however, it's a foreign key, in essence, so that we can get postal-code information.

```
public string Zip { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Zip")]
public virtual PostalCode PostalCode { get; set; }
```

Not ideal structure...I know...

But anyway, if the user has a postal-code recognized by our system, all great, everything loads.  However, if the user has an unknown or invalid zip code, e.g. `00000`, EF sees a non-null Foreign Key and this results in the following problem:

In my view-file (so after I've disposed of my context), I check the property of our greedily-loaded entity:

```
@if( person.PostalCode != null && person.PostalCode.IsInServiceArea ) {
    <div>Service Area HTML</div>
}
```

Unfortunately, because of EF overriding my virtual property, even when there is no PostalCode, it's not NULL. So, when this code runs it throws an exception that the ObjectContext has been disposed of, which means that EF is trying to lazy-load an Entity even though it already tried to greedily load and should know it doesn't exist `:(`

**The obvious solutions (please don't answer w/ these):**

- Validate zip codes on entry and only allow ones we know about and set unknown zip codes to NULL (I like this, but I don't have time to re-engineer this)
- Get the value of IsInServiceArea while the context is opened and put it directly in my View Model so that I set the value before my context is disposed of.  (This is actually what I'm planning to do, so I don't need this answer):

**The Question**

> In Entity Framework, Code-First, what is the correct way to check to
>   see if a greedily loaded, LEFT OUTER JOIN'd entity, was loaded AFTER
>   the context is disposed of?

Based on answers I have found, (e.g. the below), I'm thinking it's likely that this is not possible without the context being open...but thought I'd ask anyway:

- [How to determine if Navigation Property in the Entity Framework is set without loading the related records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469699/how-to-determine-if-navigation-property-in-the-entity-framework-is-set-without-l)

Comment: Another obvious solution: why not just disable proxy generation altogether? In a disconnected environment like MVC, I've found that it has more drawbacks than advantages...

Comment: What do you mean by *even when there is no PostalCode, it's **not** NULL*? It should be `null`. Are you saying you have a FK which is not enforced in the database? Could you post a sample model reproducing the issue?

Comment: This is a classic case for separating view model objects from data model objects.  Do not pass the data model object to your view.  Pass a view model object to your view instead.

Comment: @youzer, As I said, I dumbed down my example. I actually do pass a View Model, not the entity, which is why I said the solution I was going with was to add IsInServiceArea to my View Model.  The ViewModel has a reference to Person for simplicity...but it's quite easy to separate when necessary.

Comment: @IvanStoev, As I said in my post, I could re-engineer this code, which I would like, but it's not on my time-table.  PostalCode is a typed entry by the user that was not previously linked to any PostalCode DB.  The Primary Key of the PostalCode DB is a CHAR(5).  So, the PostalCode entry in the Person is not a true key at this point...that will have to be a later re-work.

Comment: @AkosNagy, that actually sounds perfect if it'll work (that one wasn't obvious to me).  I probably can't disable it everywhere to avoid side-effects, but I don't like unintentional lazy-loading anyway, so it sounds like a good way to move forward.

I can technically just research it if you don't have the time, but if you can post this as an answer, and it works for this case, I'll select it.

Comment: It wasn't clear though. So the FK property is not null, but the navigation property is null. I don't think EF expects something like that, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work. Make the navigation property non virtual and pray :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, ah, sorry that wasn't clear.  That was why I had mentioned if the person had a zip of `00000` and said that making it null would be one of my obvious solutions.  I have my code working at this point, I just tweaked my View Model as I described...but I wanted to see what other people more experienced in EF might suggest.  - Thanks.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks for letting me know what part wasn't clear, hopefully my question edit makes the structure a little bit more clear. - Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Just when we see Code First and Foreign Key, we assume database managed by Code First migrations and real database foreign key constraint, which enforces that the principal record exists. Anyway, since this is really EF metadata hack, you should disable lazy loading for that navigation property by making it non virtual. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, referring back to my comment, you can disable lazy-loading and proxy creation altogether. Just find the constructor(s) of your dbcontext type, and then add these two lines into the method:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

This way you can disable it globally (whenever a context is created the ctor is run, these settings are applied).

Or, you can just disable it for one instance if you set these on the context object itself after it's created.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost the opposite of what I was looking for, but it accomplishes the purpose and forces you to have more explicit architecture so you aren't accidentally lazy-loading all over the place.  So, I'm considering this the answer for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively let your context live through the entire request so that lazy loading can be fulfilled on the view.

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    MyContext Create() { return new MyContext(); }
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Create);
    ...
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<MyContext>();
var person = context.Persons.Include( x => x.PostalCode ).FirstOrDefault();
return View(person);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've considered this, but it's a no-go for me.  I don't want to leave the connection open for the entire life of the request, and it would also have the side-effect of making un-intended lazy-loads in the view invisible.

Comment: It doesn't leave the connection open.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, where does context.Dispose() get called?

Comment: @KevinNelson Dispose will always close the connection but the connection is only open when an operation is running.